# FirebaseError: Messaging: The notification permission was not granted and blocked instead. (messaging/permission-blocked)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a React PWA, and am running into some issues while testing on a real Android device, using Chrome. When I try to load the uninstalled app via Chrome for Android, I am getting the following error:

> FirebaseError: Messaging: The notification permission was not granted and blocked instead. (messaging/permission-blocked).

However, I am not being prompted to allow notification permissions. If I install the app, then it seems that permissions are allowed, without prompt. I have installed and uninstalled the app a number of times now while testing, so I am wondering if there is something I need to clear somewhere to enable the permission prompt, but I can't find anything that has worked.

If I tap the "lock" icon in the URL bar, I see that I have the locations permissions enabled, but "notifications" is not listed at all.

I have notification prompts enabled for Chrome, and this particular app domain is not on any of the "block" lists in my settings.